# how to setContenView in fragment

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, zxing, android-mediascanner

Hello I would like to show my ZXingScanner in afragment

I've try this :

`scannerView.setResultHandler(getActivity());` and

```
scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(getActivity());
```

This is my fragment

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan_qr, container, false);
        qrCameraLayout = (LinearLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.layoutScanner);
        scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        scannerView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        qrCameraLayout.addView(scannerView);
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (scannerView == null){
            scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            qrCameraLayout.addView(scannerView);
        }
        scannerView.setResultHandler(getActivity());
        scannerView.startCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        scannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        scannerView.stopCamera();
    }
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        String scanResult = result.getText();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",null);
        builder.setMessage(scanResult);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> You don't need setContentView for fragment, it is required only for
>   activity.And you are getting inflated view as below:

```
 View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan_qr, container, false);
```

Comment: I've find a new problem